# C#, Can I move dictionary initial code out from the constructor?

Tags: c#

Here is my code right now. But I would like to move those "Add" out from the constructor. Can we initialize `Dictionary` when we `new` it? or you have another better idea. Basically I want to define few characters which are used in many places.

```
public class User
    {
        public enum actionEnum
        {
            In,
            Out,
            Fail
        }

        public static Dictionary<actionEnum, String> loginAction = new Dictionary<actionEnum, string>();

        public User()
        {
            loginAction.Add(actionEnum.In, "I");
            loginAction.Add(actionEnum.Out, "O");
            loginAction.Add(actionEnum.Fail, "F");


        }
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use C# 3's [collection initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
public static Dictionary<actionEnum, String> loginAction = new Dictionary<actionEnum, string> {
    { actionEnum.In,   "I" }, 
    { actionEnum.Out,  "O" }, 
    { actionEnum.Fail, "F" }
};
```

Note, by the way, that the dictionary is mutable; any code can add or remove values.

Comment: Didn't realize they had the multi-argument syntax.  Nice.

Comment: Not only is the dictionary itself mutable, but in both your and his code, the reference is mutable as well.  To fix the latter, mark it `readonly`.  To fix the former, well, some folks have rolled their own ReadOnlyDictionary, such as here: http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=29